# Warning: 'isTouchInside' in If Condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

Objective:

- When touch inside, the button background image be change

Code:

```
- (void)addMyButton{    // Method for creating button, with background image and other properties

    UIButton *playButton = [[UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeRoundedRect] retain];
    [self.view addSubview:playButton];
    playButton.frame = CGRectMake(150, 150, 100, 100);
    //set title,backgroundcolor...

    UIImage *buttonImageNormal = [UIImage imageNamed:@"red.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal = [buttonImageNormal stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    if([playButton isTouchInside:[UIImage buttonImageNormal]]) //This line warning
    {
        UIImage *buttonImageNormal2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"];
        UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal2 = [buttonImageNormal2 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
        [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    }
}
```

Please tell me what i did at present in the warning line.
Tell me what mistakes are.
And tell me the syntax of 'isTouchInside'. 
If u like, do my objective.

Comment: ( "<Tcharni: done my objective>",    "<Chuck: clear my mistakes>",    "<Logan: clear syntax definition>" ) - All of us given accepted answer.. What can i do now for "vote of accepted answer"!

Comment: You can give upvotes to everyone, and select an answer for whichever you thought was most helpful!

Comment: I agree with @Logan. Should be the one that provided the most help towards your question, and overall objectives

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing:

```
if([playButton isTouchInside:[UIImage buttonImageNormal]])
```

To:

```
if([playButton isTouchInside])
```

isTouchInside doesn't take any arguments

Comment: Your Syntax works. ie. No warning. But, button bvackground image still "red.png". Why?

Comment: Because your method isn't related to touch events. isTouchInside will always be NO.

Comment: What is your goal here, what behavior are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I don't know about isTouchInside till before i got answers from yours. Now, i achieved my objective what i said before.

Answer (score 1):

You tried to call a nonexistent method named `isTouchInside:` that takes a UIImage as an argument. You probably wanted `isTouchInside`, which does not take any arguments. You should use that one instead.

Answer (score 1):

If you want the button to respond to a touch event, perhaps you should add this code:

```
[playButton addTarget: self action:@selector(playButtonPressed:) forControlEvents: UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

And then add this function:

```
- (void) playButtonPressed: (id) sender{
    UIImage *buttonImageNormal2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"yellow.png"];
    UIImage *strechableButtonImageNormal2 = [buttonImageNormal2 stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:12 topCapHeight:0];
    [playButton setBackgroundImage:strechableButtonImageNormal2 forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
```

And remove the `if([playButton isTouchInside]`) block. This ensures that the button responds to touches at any time, rather than only at the time of creation.